# Trying to get page to scroll to new div after x time not working

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I have tried the following code

```
<script src="https://code.google.com/p/yes/source/browse/trunk/jquery/serialScroll/1.2.1/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function () {

$('body').delay(5000) //wait 
    .animate({

        'scrollTop': $('#headermenu_wrap').offset().top
    }, 500); //animate over 300ms, 
});
</script>
```

however the page just loads it does not scroll to the div

I have a large logo at the top of the screen that should display for a few seconds before scrolling down to the menu.

I have tried these code snippets as well with the same results

```
$(function () {
setTimeout(function () { goToSecondTab(); }, 5000);
function goToSecondTab() {
    window.location.hash = 'headermenu_wrap';
}
});
```

any suggestions

thanks

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/a2y6j/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function () {

$('body').delay(5000) //wait 
    .animate({

        scrollTop: $('#headermenu_wrap').offset().top; //unquote to scrollTop
    }, 500); //animate over 300ms, 
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I have tried adding your code but it still doesn't work this is my site http://www.saundersitsolutions.co.uk/